# Scrollable table with header and TWO fixed columns

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a system with many tables (these are fine on my wide screen, but some users what them to scroll), and I have added scrollable content with fixed headers.  To many of them without issue - there are lots of examples out there.  However in a few cases I want two columns to be fixed (and in one case, three columns).  I have tried this, but it still only fixes the first column.  (Scrolltable2 for 2 cols, Scrolltable3 for 3 cols)

```
.Scrolltable, 
.Scrolltable2, 
.Scrolltable3 {
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.Scrolltable  thead td,
.Scrolltable  thead th,
.Scrolltable2 thead td,
.Scrolltable2 thead th,
.Scrolltable3 thead td,
.Scrolltable3 thead th {
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:white;
}

.Scrolltable  thead th:first-child,
.Scrolltable2 thead th:first-child,
.Scrolltable3 thead th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Scrolltable  tbody td:first-child,
.Scrolltable2 tbody td:first-child,
.Scrolltable2 tbody td:nth-child(2),
.Scrolltable3 tbody td:first-child,
.Scrolltable3 tbody td:nth-child(2),
.Scrolltable3 tbody td:nth-child(3) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```